# HP Envy 15 Speakers Partially Working (Beats Audio)

Tags: sound, hp, alsa

Anybody have all 5 speakers (front l+r,rear l+r and woofer) working? Currently only the front two (front l+r) are working. I'm running a fresh install of 12.10. Headphones work fine though. Doesn't matter which program is producing audio either.

Answer (score 2):

The subwoofer and rear speakers are not detected in Debian. You need to correctly assign the pins using `hdajackretask`. To install `hdajackretask` execute following command in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-tools-gui
```

now run `sudo hdajackretask` in a terminal. A window will open with many options. Select the proper "Codec" and check the "Show unconnected pins" and now change the pins accordingly.

```
0x0D -> Internal Speaker

0x0F -> Internal Speaker (Back)

0x10 -> Internal Speaker (LFE) #This is the subwoofer
```

Now click on "Apply". To make the changes permanent, click on "Install boot override".